# Why does my @JsonAlias not work after merging my code?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jackson

sorry but I'm still pretty new to coding/java. My webhook isn't reading aliased data. Not sure where it's breaking.

I developed a webhook in java springboot gradle using Eclipse. My original code worked just fine. I only needed to transfer pieces of certain files into the master so rather than doing a git merge I just cloned the master code and added my parts. Post merge, the code runs successfully but it's not grabbing all the info. The payload has "user_username" which I called "username" so I used an alias plus made sure everything was imported and dependencies were listed. The only issue I can think of is my jackson-annotations version says it's overriding a 2.8 version (@JsonAlias is 2.9 and up). I don't have another annotations but I do have a jackson-core v2.8 that I tried exclude on and it still didn't work.

My class variable:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
@JsonAlias({"user_username"})
private String username;
```

My getter:

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
```

My call:

```
String commitUsername = payload.getUsername();
```

My pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I expected my commitUsername to be "root_user" but instead I get null.

Comment: If the payload has `user_name` then in alias why do you have `user_username`? Should not these two be the same?

Answer (score 4):

After hours of trying to delete, move around, and override dependencies. The issue was that master was using the outdated jackson-core. The master owner caught this too and updated so I didn't have to find a solution. Thanks for the help though.
One bandage repair: Just use what they used prior to annotations 2.9, @JsonProperty("user_username")

Comment: Thanks to "@JsonProperty("")"

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, thanks :) Turns out we had two versions, 2.8 (without JsonAlias) and 2.9 (with JsonAlias), and I didn't know about it until I started refactoring and moving modules around :)